# What are the default StandardOpenOptions in nio.file?

Tags: java, file, creation

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) oracle java tutorial:

> The OpenOptions Parameter
>
> Several of the methods in this section take an optional OpenOptions
>   parameter. This parameter is optional and the API tells you what the
>   default behavior is for the method when none is specified.

These are the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html) that they are referring to.

I have not been able to find out what it is the behaviour of a file creation without any `StandardOpenOption` specified. What are the default `StandardOpenOption`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the tutorial says, the individual methods which use OpenOptions define their defaults.

Eg. [Files.newBufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) defines the following defaults:

> If no options are present then this method works as if the CREATE,
>   TRUNCATE_EXISTING, and WRITE options are present. In other words, it
>   opens the file for writing, creating the file if it doesn't exist, or
>   initially truncating an existing regular-file to a size of 0 if it
>   exists.